# Can you detect the current value for -moz-device-pixel-ratio and -o-device-pixel-ratio using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, opera, media-queries

WebKit introduced the `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` media feature and `window.devicePixelRatio` JavaScript property, to allow web authors to detect whether their page was being rendered on an iPhone with a retina display:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007601-SW3
- http://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/archive/2011/5/Detecting_Retina_Displays_From_JavaScript_And_CSS.shtml

Mozilla and Opera have introduced equivalent media features, [`-moz-device-pixel-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio) and [`-o-device-pixel-ratio`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/). However, they don’t seem to have introduced the JavaScript property to go along with them.

Is there any way to detect the device pixel ratio via JavaScript in Firefox and Opera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test media features from JS using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.matchMedia

Comment: Ah, that’s worth a look. It doesn’t provide the actual value for the device’s pixel ratio, but it does let you test values to see if they’re the device’s value.

Comment: Right.  And it lets you do `>` tests, I would think, so worst-case you can binary-search for the right value...

Comment: This was really helpful, I couldn't find a way or doc on how to user comparison operators.  I wrote this to for webkit+moz support https://gist.github.com/4219907